# apacite produces inline citations out of text area when using custom margins and parindent

Tags: margins, citing, apa-style

The citation is outside of the text area. Seems like this has to do with custom margin and parindent specification. Any way to keep custom settings but still have citations wrap as expected?

Thanks.

Here is a MWE .tex file:

```
\documentclass[11 pt]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}\setlength{\textheight}{9.2in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.05in} \setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\par Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text textsss \cite{mweauth}. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mwe_bib}
\end{document}
```

and the MWE .bib file:

```
@book{mweauth,
    Author={Firstname Longlastname},
    Title={Book Title},
    Publisher={Publishing Company},
    Address={City, State},
    Year={2015} }
```

[image: Here is the problem.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the option `natbibapa` when loading the `apacite` package.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mwe_bib.bib}
@book{mweauth,
    Author={Firstname Longlastname},
    Title={Book Title},
    Publisher={Publishing Company},
    Address={City, State},
    Year={2015} }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}  % <-- new option: "natbibapa"
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}\setlength{\textheight}{9.2in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-.05in} \setlength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\setlength{\parindent}{30pt}

\begin{document}
\par Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text     text text textsss \cite{mweauth}. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text. Text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mwe_bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I use [natbibapa], do I need to use the natbib citation commands (in Table 2 of the apacite manual) as opposed to the apacite citation commands (in Table 1 of the apacite manual)? This will be a major change for me.

Comment: It's a one-time global search-and-replace operation, right?

Comment: In my writing going forward, I mean. I have used apacite commands for years.